# JavaScript code not running as expected on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

I am trying to link a JS file to my html page. I am using Gulp in processing my html, scss and js files, upon build they get distributed onto a dist folder.

This is a part of my Gulp code:

```
// Optimizing CSS and JavaScript 
gulp.task('useref', function() {

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    
});
```

And is the build sequence in my Gulp file:

```
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'clean:dist',
    'sass',
    ['useref', 'images', 'fonts', 'sassdoc'],
    callback
  )
})
```

I have some console logs in my js files that do get processed.

```
console.log('This is the Main.js file. It should be the 3rd and final file');
```

But not the following in same file: I have some JS code in the same main.js file that sets a nav div to position:top 0; on scroll down. But this js code never gets utilized. This is the js code I got from the help of @Commercial Suicide and it does run as a code snippet here at Stack Overflow.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
   nav = document.getElementById('nav');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
 if (body.scrollTop > 0) {
   nav.className += " no-indent"
 } else {
   nav.classList.remove("no-indent");
 }
}, true)
```

In my scss I have the nav id that is in the nav div and the no-ident class on the nav div too, that has the following css:

```
.no-indent { 
top: 0 !important;
}
```

And the link to the js file in my html file is set at the bottom of the body tag with:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The js files are just above the html files in the js folder.

And this is what the processed and minified js looks like in my distribution folder:

```
!function() {
}(), console.log("This is the Main.js file. It should be the 3rd and final file");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    nav = document.getElementById("nav");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    body.scrollTop > 0 ? nav.className += " no-indent" : nav.classList.remove("no-indent")
}, !0);
```

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, I think this has nothing to do with Gulp as you mentioned that the console line of the minified JS file is processed.*

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skwxbuv8/3/) where your script with small adjustments works fine. Even tried it locally and it still works. However you should still consider event throttle.

If the problem is still there than I guess it has something to do with your runtime environment. Another browser might help, to check if that is causing the problem. Secondly is the rest of your HTML file valid?

*Small note about your script. The scroll event is fired more than once. That will generate unnecessary class declarations at this line `nav.className += " no-indent"`. _"it is recommended to throttle the event"_ [Scroll event, developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)*

Here is a good explanation about event throttle and debounce [right here](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)

Comment: thanks, just tried out both document.onload = function() {code} and window.onload = function() {code} but still not working

Comment: @user2371684 The `console.log` line of the minified JS file executed but it's ignoring the rest of the file, right? And there are no errors or whatsoever in the log? Does it work when you don't uglify the js file?

Comment: took away the minified js file and set the link to a normal one with <script src="js/main.js"></script> The console shows the console log, and the debugger show rest of the unminified js code. 
But the code is still not working.
Can we possibly take this on a chat instead?